# Why is an Aztec diamond indeed called an Aztec diamond?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, terminology

An Azted diamond is a shape which looks like this:
[image]

I have always wondered why it was called an Aztec diamond in the first place? After a bit of research I found no link to the Aztec civilizations at all.

Comment: A search for "aztec frieze patterns" may be enlightening.  http://goo.gl/HpWdW5

Comment: I don't have a source for this being the reason, but an Aztec pyramid has large steps instead of/in addition to a smooth diagonal slope, so I imagine that was the inspiration here.

Comment: @MarkS. Your explanation is also plausible.  In any event, I would think that the idea is that there are objects from Aztec culture that look similar (to the mathematicians who named the Aztec diamond).  I doubt that there is anything more interesting going on (such as a deep link to Aztec culture).

Comment: You might want to try asking this also over at the stackexchange for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).  Looking at the '91 paper by Elkies, Kuperberg, Larsen and Propp doesn't give any reasoning behind the name, only the definition.  I'm unsure if the name goes back further than them as of yet.

Comment: I had always thought the name was due to the large steps.  David Anderson's thesis (http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/aztec.pdf) states that "In 1980, Grensing, Carlsen, and Zapp first considered one such family of subgraphs in the infinite grid, now known as Aztec diamond graphs".  I can't follow the reference, so I can't tell if G-C-Z used the word "Aztec".